# Unexpected characters on preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm using preg_replace in the wordpress menu system to output my own clean HTML that works with gumby framework. However, when I run the menu string through preg_replace

```
$menu = preg_replace('<ul>','<div class="dropdown"><ul>',$menu);
$menu = preg_replace('</ul>','</div></ul>',$menu);
```

I get unexpected results being spit out in the template where it spits out extra " "< above my dropdown replacement class.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: just use str_replace()

Comment: Did you need regex? Just use str_replace if you are replacing strings.

Comment: For starters, open and close your tags in the right order.

Comment: It doesn't work at all with str_replace

Comment: show us the str_replace()  code you tried

Comment: $menu = str_replace('<ul>','<div class="dropdown"><ul>',$menu);

$menu = str_replace('</ul>','</ul></div>',$menu);

Comment: whats teh value of $menu?

Comment: It's the Wordpress wp_nav_menu function. $menu is the full ul html for the front-end menu

Comment: its not what you think it is if that code is not working

Comment: It's weird if preg_replace was doing it fine though yeah?

Comment: no preg_replace was missing the delimiters. here is your code, working: http://codepad.org/wpHL7ppN $menu is the issue

Comment: Hmmmmmmm. There must be something in $menu that's different. I'll try and find out

Answer (score 0):

In regex, you always have a  pair of delimiters. One of the lesser-known features is that you can have a matching pair of bracket-like characters (parens, square, brace or angle) to avoid the need to escape anything inside. However, in this case, this results in your "regex" only replacing the "ul" and "/ul", not the entire tag.

To fix, just use `str_replace`. It's much cheaper, considering you're replacing static strings. Also [The Pony He Comes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Also note that your HTML tag order is wrong. If you open div then ul, you should close ul then div.

Comment: I fixed the tag order, but replacing preg_ with str_ doesn't make any difference. It doesn't add anything around the UL at all now

$menu = str_replace('<ul>','<div class="dropdown"><ul>',$menu);
$menu = str_replace('</ul>','</ul></div>',$menu);

Comment: You could also use JavaScript to change it dynamically, since that works on parsed HTML.

Comment: That's a bit nasty. Would rather the php code does what it's supposed to.